# How to extract an image area and plug it back in the original image?

Tags: python, numpy, extract, reshape, imaging

I am working with 3D images(300) of size (128x128x128). I want to extract the image area (remove the background), do some transformation, and plug the transformed part back on the original image. How can I do this in python?

This is what I tried:

I created a mask which has the shape `(128, 128, 128)`. I then got the `np.sum` on that mask  `n_voxels_flattened = np.sum(mask)` (removed the zero voxels so that I can do the transformation on non-zeros voxels) where now the `n_voxels_flattened=962517`. Then iterated over all images (300 images) which resulted in an array with shape `(962517, 300)`. I did some adjustments to this array and the output has the same shape as input:`(962517, 300)`. I now want to reshape this array and put back the zero voxels I removed so that it has the shape `(128,128,128,300)`.

This is what I tried, but it resulted in a weird looking image when visualized.

```py
zero_array = np.zeros((128*128*128 * 300))   
zero_array[:len(result.reshape(-1))]=result.reshape(-1)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if I've read your question correctly, you want to apply some function, `f`, to all the voxels which are not background pixels (`0`)?

In that case, you can do this using the `np.where` function in `numpy`, but I'll provide a longer example which does the same thing, too.

`np.where` has two modes. When you specify the optional second and third arguments, it will insert all the values from the second argument into a new array where the condition is `True`, and the values from the third argument where the condition is `False`.

Example using `np.where`

```py
import numpy as np

# I used 3 to test because your original array is quite large,
# but you can change this back to (128, 128, 128, 300).
# I would suggest you iterate over this instead of having such a large
# single array object.
shape = (128,128,128,3)

# Computing some random data to try and emulate your situation
voxels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=shape)

# I'm going to use np.power(x, 2) as my transformation function
# because I don't know what you're doing with the voxels 
# so you can just replace this with your actual transformation function.
output_voxels = np.where(voxels != 0, np.power(voxels, 2), voxels)

print(output_voxels.shape)
# (128, 128, 128, 3)
```

This results in a new array, where all voxels which are not `0` have been raised to a power of 2, and all voxels which are `0` are filled with their original value, `0`.

Longer example using array masking directly.

```py
import numpy as np

shape = (128,128,128,3)

voxels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=shape)

# Index the array to find all the data which is not equal to 0.
# Here we are using an inverse (~) mask so it has to be in brackets,
# Alternatively you could use voxels[voxels != 0]
valid_voxels = voxels[~(voxels == 0)]

# Simple transformation function to emulate your situation.
transformed_valid_voxels = np.power(valid_voxels, 2)

# Define a new array in the same shape as the input data.
output_voxels = np.zeros(shape=shape)

# Assign the new pixels to the output where the mask is applied.
output_voxels[~(voxels == 0)] = transformed_valid_voxels

print(output_voxels.shape)
# (128, 128, 128, 3)
```

Hope I read the question correctly.